# How to log all routes in NextJS

Tags: node.js, logging, next.js

I'm very new to NextJS - I currently have a pretty simple app that serves a handful of pages, and returns a 404 page if the route doesn't exist.

I'd like to get logging for every request, including pages that don't exist and return a 404 page. I'm running the app inside a docker container, or I'd like the logs to be written to stdout but not visible in chrome console out.

What's the best way to implement this?

Comment: Same, deployed with docker https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#docker-image, now need to find a solution for logs

Answer (score 1):

This use-case sounds like an access-log setup.

The best way would be to setup a reverse proxy like nginx so it can create logs in your docker container.

If you don't want to do that, you can follow these two steps

1. Setup a custom server that gets the request https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server
2. Use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-bunyan to write out your logs

If you would like access from the front-end to be logged as well as they traverse the application - You could use something like a Google analytics account to capture both client and server side events.

Comment: thanks - this got me started. I'm able to log things correctly when in dev mode, but how can I do this when using SSG?

Comment: The only reason I can see for this not being built-in is that they're trying to upsell people onto their vercel platform. There's simply no other excuse...

Answer (score 1):

One way is to patch `nextjs` into producing logs (`production`, `output: 'standalone'`):

`nextjs 12.x`:

```
sed -Ei \
    -e '/await handler/iconst __start = new Date;' \
    -e '/await handler/aconsole.log(`-- [${__start.toISOString()}] ${((new Date - __start) / 1000).toFixed(3)} ${req.method} ${req.url}`);' \
    server.js
```

`nextjs 13.x, 14.x`:

```
sed -Ei \
    -e '/await requestHandler/iconst __start = new Date;' \
    -e '/await requestHandler/aconsole.log(`-- [${__start.toISOString()}] ${((new Date - __start) / 1000).toFixed(3)} ${req.method} ${req.url}`);' \
    node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
```

[steps to reproduce](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f4a2f1363ae5c08981c257cc406e00ac)

You can use [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) for this.

If you need it in development:

`nextjs 12.x`:

```
$ cp node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js.bak
$ sed -Ei \
    -e '/return requestHandler/iconst __start = new Date;' \
    -e '/return requestHandler/aconsole.log(`-- [${__start.toISOString()}] ${((new Date - __start) / 1000).toFixed(3)} ${req.method} ${req.url}`); return __r;' \
    -e '/return requestHandler/s/return/const __r = /' \
    node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
```

`nextjs 13.x, 14.x`:

```
$ cp node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js.bak
$ sed -Ei \
    -e '/await requestHandler/iconst __start = new Date;' \
    -e '/await requestHandler/aconsole.log(`-- [${__start.toISOString()}] ${((new Date - __start) / 1000).toFixed(3)} ${req.method} ${req.url}`);' \
    node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It helped me with a solution based on patch-package and pino-http. Have wrote about it in case it can help others: 

https://www.tomups.com/posts/log-nextjs-request-response-as-json/

Answer (score 0):

If you're already on `AWS` and have your nextJS server running behind `CloudFront` you can easily enable request logging for the corresponding distribution and get this feature "free" without making any nextJS changes. This is also the most performant option IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a proxy, which works quite well.

Follow the steps below to get it working on Linux.

**Install `Caddy`:**

```bash
sudo snap install caddy --edge
```

**Create a `Caddyfile` in your project/repository directory with the following content:**

```
:3000 {
    reverse_proxy localhost:3001

    log {
        output stdout
        format console
    }
}
```

**Run the proxy server:**

```
caddy run
```

**It's assumed that your NodeJS server is running on port `3001`:**

```
yarn dev --port 3001
```