# Add server logging for next.js standalone (Output File Tracing)

Tags: next.js

Next.js has a feature called [Output File Tracing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing). It allows to create production version of next.js app with only required files included. That drastically reduces bundle size. It also generates `server.js` file which you can use to run your next app. The server file is quite simple except for the part that it adds some configuration variables (see `conf` property in example below):

```
...
const http = require('http');
...
const nextServer = new NextServer({
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: currentPort,
  dir: path.join(__dirname),
  dev: false,
  conf: {"env":{},"webpackDevMiddleware":...,<large array of configuration values>},
});
...
```

Some of the values seems to be taken from `next.config.js` but I am not sure where the others come from.

I want to have my custom `server.js` file where I would implement logging which would log all request to next server. When there are some other ways to implement logging, I found this to be the easiest in terms of simply logging everything.

Also this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62698896/8367627) suggests to use custom server to achieve my goal.

My problem is that I am not sure how the these `conf` are generated, and what should I include into my custom `server.js` file. I also would prefer that I would not need to update `server.js` file each time I update some configuration in my app as this can be easily missed.

How does this `conf` property generated and can I replace it with something myself?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to include the `conf` property? Have you tried omitting it?

Comment: I tried to omit it. I am getting an error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'distDir')` `distDir` is one of the variables that is generated. I also tried to omit variable `imageSizes` [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#image-sizes). It breaks the app. So aparently this `conf` is needed if I create new `NextServer` instance.

Comment: From the sources, https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/03eb4b1d612513506a441137a4997bd137e3b014/packages/next/build/utils.ts#L1481