# How to make NextJS output access logs?

Tags: logging, next.js

By default NextJS doesn't output access logs, when I use `yarn start` it only tells that the service is ready:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ next start
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
```

Is there a way to make it output access logs? For instance, Apache append an access.log file that looks like:

```
192.168.2.20 - - [28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0300] "GET /cgi-bin/try/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3395
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2006:10:22:04 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2216
```

Is there a config on nextjs to enable access logs?

Comment: Hello, did you find a way for it?

Comment: No, I didn't. We stopped looking for this after we integrated with New Relic. But it would still be useful.

Comment: Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78067195/52499), but maybe you want to add a reverse proxy in front of your app instead.